# Multiple stage3D instances on mobile, is it possible?

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, stage3d

I have the following doubt, in an app that I'm developing sometimes I need to show a video that will sit in the top right corner, like this:

[image]

The thing is, I need this to work in mobile, and if I've read correctly, there is no way to have more than one stage3D instance, so this approach wont work.

The other option is, to convert the static (cyan) area to native display list, which solves the problem, but I could maybe run into performance issues?, I will need to test.

Any other ideas to have a video like in the layout?.

Comment: Can't you just use three different vertex arrays when rendering the three components to the stage?

Comment: @Conduit I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: First you can have many stage3d instance running and displaying, they just can't be transparent so there's little use for that. Using classic displayobject on mobile is just fine as long as you manage correctly memory. Avoid all vector and use as much as possible bitmaps. I've made a lot of apps running only bitmap (with vector converter) and keeping a steady 60fps without ever needing stage3d.

Comment: The thing is, the stage3D layer cannot be transparent, which means I need to have 2 instances of stage3D, only one wont do.

Comment: conduit is mistaken or doesn't explain very well. Doesn't matter if you render something or not in your stage3d instance, your stage3d instance will cover the area defined by its size and position (and base color), another stage3d instance can display on top of it but rendering glitches are likely to appear. And unlike conduit said stage3d instances do not render anything on the stage.

Comment: @BotMaster Yep - messed up my terminology. Deleted the old comment, rewriting here: 

A stage3D layer uses a vertex buffer to determine the area used when rendering. If there are several different items that need to be rendered and you only have one stage3d layer, then you can create a texture containing the final visual representation of the component/video/whatever, set the vertex buffer to the rendering area you want to show that component, and then render the texture to the newly altered vertex buffer. [Info here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/how-stage3d-works.html).

Comment: but that would be unpractical conduit since uploading texture to gpu takes too long.

Comment: And I still don't see how you can bypass the problem that the stageVideo layer is always rendered behind the rectangular area of the stage3D.

Comment: It looks like the components are already placed using stage3d - regardless of the implementation (render from texture, render from something else) limiting the vertex buffer so it doesn't place anything over the video on the stage should work, no? The  video will come through as long as nothing is rendered on the stage3d layer in a position directly above it.

Comment: The only way to display the video is if 1) I don't have anything on top of it 2) the visible property is set to false.